# Laravel + JS Vue

Tags: node.js, vue-component, laravel-5.8

Just start a tutorial about Laravel 5.8 (from 0) and trying to add some JS to the project. Installed NodeJS: npm -v: 6.10.1; node -v: 12.6.0; Then install npm in the project and use npm run watch. After all change ExampleComponent.vue to MyButton.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="my-button" v-text="test.name">My Button</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')

            axios.post('api/vue', {})
                .then(response => {
                    this.test = response.data
                });
        },

        data: function () {
            return {
                test: null,
            }
        },
        props: [
            'text'
        ]
    }
</script>

<style>
    .my-button{
        background-color: #333333;
    }
</style>
```

Register it in app.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('my-button', require('./components/MyButton.vue').default);

let app;
app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

then in my view add:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <div id="app">
                        <my-button text="My new test button"></my-button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

[app.js component error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQE0T.jpg)

After all, I got the report from Laravel mix that build success:

> DONE Compiled successfully in 16733ms 4:51:01 PM

But in the browser, I didn't see my button. I've tried cleaning the cache. But it doesn't help. Someone any suggestions?

Comment: Do you see the ('Component mounted.') in the console? Do you have something in the Vue.js devtools (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vue-js-devtools/)

Comment: Mhm, ok find where I have to check it. In the console I have an error:
app.js:38569 [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app
warn @ app.js:38569